# how to calculate time for engine on and off in mysql

Tags: mysql

for example i have 8 datas in mysql...

```
id     car     time                              engine
1       BMW     2012-02-25 04:00:00                off
2       BMW     2012-02-25 04:02:44                on
3       BMW     2012-02-25 04:06:22                off
4       BMW     2012-02-25 04:10:11                off
5       BMW     2012-02-25 04:15:00                on
6       BMW     2012-02-25 04:20:00                on
7       BMW     2012-02-25 04:25:00                off
8       BMW     2012-02-25 04:30:00                off
```

i want to output data like this :

car off engine :2012-02-25 04:00:00                    duration: 00:02:44
car off engine :2012-02-25 04:06:22                       duration:  00:03:49
car off engine :2012-02-25 04:25:00                        duration: 00:05:00

i confused how to calculate my off engine time in my data...please help me to solve my proble...

Comment: do u want to sum up ur off engine times?

Comment: your data model is unclear.  Does each row represent a _sample_ of the engine's state, or a specific transition?

Comment: Define exactly what time do you want to calculate. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: sorry i am newbie...i use mysql and php and i add my question with what i want for the output

Comment: Is your data correct with the mis-paired on/off entries where you have two ON back-to-back and two OFF back-to-back?  Also, as Venk asked, do you want the time the engine is in the "ON" mode (ie: total running time)  or in the "OFF" (total doing nothing time).

Comment: Has anyone find the answer, i have same question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('car off engine',A.time,'duration :',SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(A.time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(B.time)))
FROM
(SELECT * FROM data WHERE engine='on' ORDER BY time) A,
(SELECT * FROM data WHERE engine='off' ORDER BY time) B
WHERE A.id+1=B.id;
```

Comment: Nope.. not at all.. I was typing this answer... and left my desk for some reason.. by the time i came back it got posted and received two down votes... :)

Comment: The query is missing the closing parenthesis to the CONCAT function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to calculate the total time the car was off given a list of "off" and "on" timestamps like you listed, you'll want to order these timestamps in ascending order, then calculate the total off time by calculating the sum of the intervals between off & on.

This can be done by using some programming language to iterate through the ordered(by time) list of offs and ons.  When an "off" is encountered, get the time elapsed between that "off" occurrence and the next "on" occurrence.  The sum of these times elapsed is your total off time.  Or you can just output these times elapsed as you iterate through, and then you'll be able to see the amount of time the car was off after each "off" occurrence.

Comment: This is not an mysql answer

Answer (score 0):

This will give the time that each row is valid -

```
SELECT d1.*, SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d2.time)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(d1.time)) AS duration
FROM data d1
INNER JOIN data d2
    ON d1.id + 1 = d2.id
ORDER BY d1.id ASC;
```

To take this any further we would need more details about the result set you require.