# MySQL - Calculate downtime of a motor based on power values

Tags: mysql, calculation, downtime

I would like to ask for your support with the following.

I would like to calculate the daily downtime (Power = 0) of a motor with a MySQL query. The table structure and sample of my dataset - below - has only timestamp and motor power. The data sampling rate is 10 seconds.

Table structure
(Datum Timestamp, Pot int);

Data set sample
|     Timestamp       |Power|
|     ---------       | --- |
| 2023-10-06 21:43:40 | 474 |
| 2023-10-06 21:43:50 | 0   |
| 2023-10-06 21:45:40 | 0   |
| 2023-10-06 21:45:50 | 40  |
| 2023-10-06 21:53:50 | 245 |
| 2023-10-06 21:54:00 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 09:15:40 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 09:15:50 | 2   |
| 2023-10-07 09:28:50 | 322 |
| 2023-10-07 09:29:00 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 09:30:40 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 09:30:50 | 9   |
| 2023-10-07 12:59:10 | 471 |
| 2023-10-07 12:59:20 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 13:42:20 | 0   |
| 2023-10-07 13:42:30 | 82  |

I created my own query, but it only managed to calculate with the daily max and the min timestamps. Hence, the downtimes happening within the day were - not on purpose - ignored. It also ignored the date change between the 6th. and the 7th. (the fiddle is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/Z3K4CIRR )
When I use a cloud-based analysis service, the result of the same query is
Date        Daily Downtime [%]  Daily Uptime [%]
2023-10-06  9           91
2023-10-07  57          43
which is in any case wrong

I have tried adapting my data to a customized version of these solutions; however, the result I get is quite different from the manually calculated downtimes.

1. [how to calculate time for engine on and off in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703662/how-to-calculate-time-for-engine-on-and-off-in-mysql)
2. [Calculate downtime based on status 'UP' / 'DOWN'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088682/calculate-downtime-based-on-status-up-down)
3. [Find downtimes and calculate lengths of downtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55974720/find-downtimes-and-calculate-lengths-of-downtime)
4. [calculate downtime based on status values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317874/calculate-downtime-based-on-status-values)

Moreover, most of the datasets in the solutions have a “Status” somewhere; I have a power value.

It is also possible I have not fully “digested” the solutions and I have somewhere a mistake (highly probable, as I am a newbie in this topic)

I would like to get the following result for the sample data shown above:

| Date | Downtime | Daily downtime [%] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-06 | 02:07:50 | 8,9 |
| 2023-10-07 | 10:00:20 | 42 |

With this result I could carry on with other KPI’s of the motor.

Thanks a lot!
MySQL GreenBoy

Comment: One thing you can consider is converting datatime into UnixTimestamp format so when you have to compare dates and times against each other, doing this turns the date into a number like 1697728994 which makes doing math with it MUCH easier than having to think about leap years, midnight 1 to 24 hour back to 1 issues, all that stuff, then when you get the math done, convert them back to dates.  It just simplifies everything and it should work for at least then next 18 years.

Comment: Thanks @easleyfixed. That's a great hint! I will give it a try.

Comment: Somehow the query works. I adapted this [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/how-to-calculate-total-on-hours-and-total-off-hours-in-day-of-a-motor-using-php). My fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ockNc8vz). I get similar results when comparing to the manual calculation and the difference can be neglected. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it working, keeping being curious :)